# VMWare NAT not populating ARP with IP/MAC from VMWare host only?

Tags: virtual-machine, vmware-player, arp

I ran into a problem while penetration testing with Netdiscover on a virtual set up using VMPlayer, free version.  The attack machine is on the VMWare NAT network interface, and the target machines are on VMWare host-only.  I discovered that Netdiscover was not working because the VMWare NAT interface had not populated its ARP table with the IP/MAC of the target machines (Netdiscover uses ARP).  All other tested protocols from the NAT to host-only (http, ping) worked without issue.  Original issue is at https://security.stackexchange.com/q/105263/91684.

I looked at the  VMWare documentation and found nothing clear on how the ARP are populated.

Is this normal VMWare behavior, or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: AFAIK netdiscover does not rely on the ARP cache, but will send ARP requests to actively map nodes. What happens when using `netdiscover -r range` for a range that includes the target machines?

Comment: @harrymc Please refer to the link in the question for full background and research.

Comment: Coming to think about it, ARP requests probably cannot cross from one VMnet? adapter to another, because VMware does not define a Default Gateway for its adapters. You might need to use the route command to define the necessary routes, or create an ARP Proxy, or add a Default Gateway (if possible in your environment).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Netdiscover](http://nixgeneration.com/~jaime/netdiscover/) works ...

> by actively sending arp requests

Arp requests do not cross gateways. For one thing, on Linux machines we activate `IPv4` forwarding, but IPv4 packets are OSI-Layer 3 objects, while ARP requests are OSI-Layer 2 objects, so that nowhere in a Linux kernel is there an instruction to forward ARP requests to another interface.

This is **exactly** your case: once an ARP request reaches the host's interface, it will be discarded because the IP for which the MAC is required does not match the interface's. Nor will the request be forwarded to another interface because of the above reason. Hence your host (correctly) drops the ARP request, which will go unanswered. This explains the failure of Netdiscover in your setup.

The above failure is not due to the fact that in VMWare there is no proper gateway between the different networks. Even neglecting the impossibility of Linux servers to forward anything but IPv4 objects (*i.e.*,assuming you have non-Linux gateway/routers), the most common behavior for gateways is to respond to ARP requests of remote hosts with *their own MAC address*, see for instance [here under ARP operation for a remote host](http://www.tildefrugal.net/tech/arp/). In other words, there is no upstream chain of ARP requests until the MAC address of a remote host is matched to the IP provided. Nor is the minimum behavior described above (returning the MAC address of the local gateway) common.

All of this can be easily tested: on a Debian machine

```
  sudo apt-get install iputils-arping 
  sudo arping -f -c 1 -w 5 -I eth0 8.8.8.8
```

and something similar to this on all other OSes. You will see you get no replies. You may also use `traceroute` to find the IP addresses of some of your own upstream gateways; the command

```
  sudo arping -f -c 1 -w 5 -I eth0 IP_of_Upstream_Gateway
```

will also go unanswered.

In order to test `Netdiscover` on your setup, you will have to place all of your VMs, attacker and attackees, on the **same subnet**. Then ARP will work.